# itextpdf acrofields format as Percentage

Tags: itextpdf

I use ITextPdf feom c# code.
I use acrofields to populate a form with data. I am losing my formatting.

```
Stream os = new FileStream(PDFPath, FileMode.CreateNew);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(memIO);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os, '9', true);
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("Pgo", 1.0  "Percentage");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are losing all your formatting. This leads to the assumption that your form contains JavaScript that formats fields when a human user enters a value.

When you fill out a form using iText, the JavaScript methods that are triggered when a form is filled out manually, aren't executed. Hence `1.0` will not be changed into `100%`.

I assume that this is a typo:

```
fields.SetField("Pgo", 1.0  "Percentage");
```

This line doesn't even compile. Your IDE should show an error when typing this line. Even if I would add the missing comma between the second and third parameter (assuming that `1.0` and `"Percentage"` are two separate parameters), you'd get an error saying that there is no `setField()` method that accepts a `String`, a `double` and a `String`.

There are two `setField()` methods:

- [`setField(String name, String value)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#setField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)): the first parameter is the key (e.g. `"Pgo"`), the second one is the value (e.g. the `String` value `"1.0"`).
- [`setField(String name, String value, String display)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#setField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)): the first parameter is the key (e.g. `"Pgo"`), the second one is the value (e.g. the `String` value `"1.0"`), and the third parameter is what should be displayed (e.g. `"100%"`).

For instance, when you do this:

```
fields.SetField("Pgo", "1.0", "100%");
```

iText will display 100%, but the value of the field will be 1.0.

If somebody clicks the field, 1.0 could appear, so that the end user can change the field, for instance into 0.5. It will depend on the presence of formatting JavaScript whether or not this manually entered 0.5 will be displayed as 50% or not.

P.S.: this question was also posted as a pre-sales question in our ticketing system at iText Software. I am closing that ticket so that the ticket won't be answered twice. By the way: this *new* question is nothing more than a rehash of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276863/pdfstamper-remove-my-formats-in-my-form. That question was unclear. Why did you ignore my request to clarify? It is not custom to post a duplicate question when you didn't get an answer the first time. You should have updated your original question.

Comment: This simply does not work. I created a new PDF without any JavaScript, and no matter what the 'display' parameter contains, the pdf will show the 2nd parameter.

Comment: If you want to display the value with appearance, use the overload which takes 4 arguments