# ITextSharp - Field's font size to be change after click on the field

Tags: pdf, itext

I try to fill data to PDF form using iTextSharp. When I use Adobe Reader to open that PDF, i can see the data has been filled into the field. But when I click on the field, the font size will be changed and if i modify the content, the font size will be fixed. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5tk7KqtLjSzdXBkckJ3M25PNVk) is my PDF file

Additional Information:
If i set the field font to "Times Roman", it won't have this issue.

```
BaseFont bfChinese = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\mingliu.ttc,0", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms, '\0', true);


            AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
            pdfFormFields.AddSubstitutionFont(bfChinese);

            pdfFormFields.SetField("Text1", "Testing Message");
            pdfFormFields.SetField("Text2", "Testing Message");

            pdfStamper.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Is it correct that the file referred to has blank fields? Would it be possible to provide a filled version as well? Aside of some rendering updates when leaving the field, I could not see any changes in either field when filling it in Acrobat XI Pro.

Comment: Hi Max, the filled version in here. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5tk7KqtLjSzbGZVcjZ6ZFd2YkE)

Comment: I don't have time to go into detail but I can tell you that this has to do with the field's "appearance" values. Although not directly related to your question, [Bruno's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27718525/231316) goes into further detail on what these are.

Comment: The appearance stream for the second field generated by iText uses the substitution font here, MingLiU. Adobe Reader, on the other hand, uses the original field font, PMingLiU. Different fonts, different metrics...

Comment: Hi @mkl, I have try to change the second field font to MingLiU in PDF. but when i try to field the data , it is the same behavior.  I have update the PDF file in [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5tk7KqtLjSzcC1pc09SM05sYW8).

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas , I had add the code pdfFormFields.GenerateAppearances = true; pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("Text2", "textfont", bfChinese, null); to set the field's appearance but not working. Would you mind to let me know how to setup the field's appearance?